# How to scroll to particular to in a another page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, smooth-scrolling

I have given href link for readmore button like this

```
<a href="about.html#post2">readmore</a>
```

in my index.html page. I have used bootstrap3 and there are scroll animation for navbar sections.
Now when I click on that readmore button in my index.html page cursor should animate to about us page and it should have a scroll animation to go for particular DIV. is this can be achievable? Should I provide the whole project here?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in this user's question [smooth scrolling to a div in a different html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462046/smooth-scrolling-to-a-div-in-a-different-html-page)